# jQuery include html - adding class to header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to include a header to my main index page (as well as other pages). I want to highlight different items of the nav bar (which is in the `header.html`) using CSS depending on which page the user is currently on. Say if the user is on the Home page, then CSS will add a class to the Home item of the nav bar found in `header.html`. The problem I'm having is that the class doesn't get added, presumably because I'm trying to add a class to an element that is in another (jQuery loaded) file

`index.html` looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.html");
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <script>
      $('.homeNav > a').addClass("navSelected");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above is the main page of the site, where I'm using jQuery to load `header.html` into the div in the body. Then in my body script tag I add the class `navSelected` to the header element

`header.html` looks like this:

```
<header>
  <h1>title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <span class="homeNav"><a href="/">Home</a></span>
  <span class="contactNav"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></span>
</nav>
```

So when the user hits this page, I want to add the `navSelected` class to the span with class `homeNav` in `header.html`, but the class does not get added and I'm not sure what the fix is.

If I use jQuery to add the class from within `header.html` then the class gets added fine, but that defeats the purpose of only highlighting the nav item relevant to the page the user is currently on

Comment: I am not sure but try this approach:
`$("#header").load("header.html",function(){$('.homeNav > a').addClass("navSelected");});`

Comment: @PeterDarmis that approach really makes no sense. If selector alone doesn't work why would `find()` work?

Comment: Sorry for that yes. @charlietfl

Comment: Isn't the consept to add class to the menu item selected? Isn't it conected with a click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `load()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax`, and it's asynchronous.

You have to wait for the content to load, before you can manipulate it, and you'd do that by using the callback

```
$(function(){
    $("#header").load("header.html", function() {
        $('.homeNav > a').addClass("navSelected");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `$('.homeNav > a')` probably fail to find the DOM elements because this line is executed before the content is loaded (created). So use the callback of `load` like @KartikeyaSharma suggested.

There is a little change that the AJAX callback doesn't work because the creation of DOM elements takes time, so it is safer to call this function at the end of header.html:

```
 onNavReady = function (){$('.homeNav > a').addClass("navSelected");}
```

Inside your header.html call this function at the end

```
...
<span class="contactNav"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></span>
<script>onNavReady()></script>
```

Comment: a `<span>` has no `onload` event. Very few elements do. There is nothing wrong with calling the code inside the completion callback directly after the elements are inserted

Comment: You are right about onload event. But the AJAX callback is fired after the GET/POST request completes, not the creation of DOM elements. Although the change is small , but it can still fail.

Comment: As shown in the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/305f193aa57014dc7d8fa0739a3fefd47166cd44/src/ajax/load.js) of load(), insertion of html and invoke of the callback are done in two separated callback `done()` and `always()` respectively. I don't see any guarantee that the DOM is created *before* the callback is invoked. A much more serious problem is that the AJAX request may fail ... and the callback is invoked in any case.

Comment: Have been using `load()` for 10 years, since early days of jQuery...never had a problem. Doesn't matter if the `addClass()` got called and element doesn't exist anyway...will fail silently when selector doesn't exist